# Script went weird with 20 errors which don't make sense (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Long story short, I was adding some code to my game I'm working on, but out of nowhere, 20 errors, they don't make sense at all. At least as I see it, it's a glitch, but how do I fix it?

here's the code and the errors (there are more errors but all pretty much the same)
Errors redirect to random parts of the code that aren't in any case an error, so I'm really wondering why it's doing this and I can't work on my game anymore

[image]

```
     using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PlayerCore : MonoBehaviour

{
    // Health Variables
    public int MaxHealth = 2;
    public int Health;
    // Other Variables
    private bool DelayCheck = true;


    // Part about taking damage and taking damage when colliding with platforms that do damage and level borders
    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health = Health - Damage;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator DelayBetweenDamage()
     {
        DelayCheck = false;
        TakeDamage(1);
        Debug.Log("Player took 1 damage.");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        DelayCheck = true;

    }

    // Take Damage when touching platforms with the DMG_platform tag
    void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "DMG_platform" && DelayCheck == true) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(DelayBetweenDamage());
        }


    }

    // Take fatal damages when falling or going out of the map borders
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Level_Border")
        {
            TakeDamage(MaxHealth);
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Part about Bonus getting triggered and applying them to the player

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Power")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            
            // if player touches Power Jump Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Jump")
            {
                \[SerializeField\] private Jump jump;
                jump.jumpVelocity = 22f;
            }
            
            // if player touches Power Health Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Health")
            {
                MaxHealth = 3;
                if (Health <= 2)
                {
                    Health = Health + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Dies if Health is less than 0 
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
        
        
    }




}
```

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You broke the syntax structure.
I reformatted the code, here it is

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCore : MonoBehaviour

{
    // Health Variables
    public int MaxHealth = 2;

    public int Health;

    // Other Variables
    private bool DelayCheck = true;


    // Part about taking damage and taking damage when colliding with platforms that do damage and level borders
    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health = Health - Damage;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator DelayBetweenDamage()
    {
        DelayCheck = false;
        TakeDamage(1);
        Debug.Log("Player took 1 damage.");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        DelayCheck = true;
    }

    // Take Damage when touching platforms with the DMG_platform tag
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "DMG_platform" && DelayCheck == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DelayBetweenDamage());
        }
    }

    // Take fatal damages when falling or going out of the map borders
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Level_Border")
        {
            TakeDamage(MaxHealth);
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Part about Bonus getting triggered and applying them to the player

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Power")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);

            // if player touches Power Jump Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Jump")
            {
                jump.jumpVelocity = 22f;
            }
            
            // if player touches Power Health Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Health")
            {
                MaxHealth = 3;
                if (Health <= 2)
                {
                    Health = Health + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Dies if Health is less than 0 
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private Jump jump;
}
```

Comment: was it that simple lol what a shame of myself, thank you hahaha

Answer (score 2):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Power")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            
            // if player touches Power Jump Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Jump")
            {
                \[SerializeField\] private Jump jump;
                jump.jumpVelocity = 22f;
            }
            
            // if player touches Power Health Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Health")
            {
                MaxHealth = 3;
                if (Health <= 2)
                {
                    Health = Health + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is wrong, do this instead :

```
if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Jump")
            {
                Jump jump;
                jump.jumpVelocity = 22f;
            }
```

you cannot declare a variable with a private field in a method.
Moreover, I advise you to declare this variable as you did for the health variables

Answer (score 1):

The script below has been modified and fixed.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCore : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Jump jump;
    
    // Health Variables
    public int MaxHealth = 2;
    public int Health;
    // Other Variables
    private bool DelayCheck = true;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;
    }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Dies if Health is less than 0 
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    // Part about taking damage and taking damage when colliding with platforms that do damage and level borders
    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health = Health - Damage;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator DelayBetweenDamage()
    {
        DelayCheck = false;
        TakeDamage(1);
        Debug.Log("Player took 1 damage.");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        DelayCheck = true;
    }

    // Take Damage when touching platforms with the DMG_platform tag
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "DMG_platform" && DelayCheck == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DelayBetweenDamage());
        }
    }

    // Take fatal damages when falling or going out of the map borders
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Level_Border")
        {
            TakeDamage(MaxHealth);
        }
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Part about Bonus getting triggered and applying them to the player
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        // if player touches Power Health Bonus
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Health")
        {
            MaxHealth = 3;
            if (Health <= 2)
            {
                Health = Health + 1;
            }
        }
        
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Power")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
        // if player touches Power Jump Bonus
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Power Jump")
        {
            jump.jumpVelocity = 22f;
        }
    }
}
```